# Should cron be able to send emails with Unicode characters?

Tags: linux, cron

This is my user `crontab`:

```
* * * * * : Subject 1;  echo Text 1; touch ~/1 2>&1
* * * * * : Subject 2; echo Text 2;  touch ~/2 2>&1
* * * * * : Subject 3;  echo Text 3;  touch ~/3 2>&1
```

Emails are received successfully for task 3; also, files `1`, `2` and `3` are `touch`ed every minute.

But I am not receiving any emails for tasks 1 and 2. Is this known/expected? How should I fix this?

This is the `env` as seen by my user crontab:

```
MAILTO=bers@company
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
MAILFROM=bers@company
XDG_SESSION_ID=234567
USER=bers
PWD=/home/bers
HOME=/home/bers
SHELL=/bin/sh
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=bers
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/123456/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/123456
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I should also say that I can use the `mail` program to send emails with Unicode characters both in the text and in the body (it sets the content type to utf8 if that happens, as expected).

So I have tried to change the `CONTENT_TYPE` in my `crontab` as well, without success:

```
CONTENT_TYPE="text/html; charset=utf-8"
CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING=utf8
```

This sends HTML emails (`multipart/alternative`) with each part, both `plain` and `html`, encoded as "utf8". But no emails for tasks 1 and 2.

I also double-checked that the locale is set (as seen from a `cron` job):

```
ws01:~> locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I am using cronie-1.5.1-lp151.4.3.1.src on OpenSUSE Leap 15.1 by the way.

Comment: Maybe related: https://serverfault.com/questions/642134

Comment: Also, https://askubuntu.com/questions/9743

Comment: If your question would be closed here, I suggest to check also https://unix.stackexchange.com , https://serverfault.com or https://askubuntu.com , where it would be likely on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it looks like this is the SMTP server's fault, which does not support `SMTPUTF8` (the subject line is part of the header, so  triggers PostFix to request that: http://www.postfix.org/SMTPUTF8_README.html)

Interestingly, I do get error messages through `mail` about non-delivered email when I include UTF-8 characters in the recipient list, but not when I include them in the subject, even though both are part of the header.

My workaround it to replace  by `=?UTF-8?B?8J+RjQ==?=`